# In javascript, is accessing 'window.Math' slower or faster than accessing the 'Math' object without the 'window.'?

Tags: javascript, performance, window, global-variables, global

I'm kind of curious about what the best practice is when referencing the 'global' namespace in javascript, which is merely a shortcut to the `window` object (or vice versia depending on how you look at it).

I want to know if:

```
var answer = Math.floor(value);
```

is better or worse than:

```
var answer = window.Math.floor(value);
```

Is one better or worse, even slightly, for performance, resource usage, or compatibility?

Does one have a slighter higher cost? (Something like an extra pointer or something)

**Edit note**:  While I am a readability over performance nazi in most situations, in this case I am ignoring the differences in readability to focus solely on performance.

Comment: Why does it matter? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: well, I am optimizing for performance, so I'm kind of curious which one is faster.  If I do thousands of calculations, one less pointer dereference per loop, will probably help me out.

Comment: "Not a real question"? This is a good question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, never compare things like these for performance reasons. `Math.round` is obviously easier on the eyes than `window.Math.round`, and you wouldn't see a noticeable performance increase by using one or the other. So don't obfuscate your code for very slight performance increases.

However, if you're just curious about which one is faster... I'm not sure how the global scope is looked up "under the hood", but I would guess that accessing `window` is just the same as accessing `Math` (`window` and `Math` live on the same level, as evidenced by `window.window.window.Math.round` working). Thus, accessing `window.Math` would be slower.

Also, the way variables are looked up, you would see a performance increase by doing `var round = Math.round;` and calling `round(1.23)`, since all names are first looked up in the current local scope, then the scope above the current one, and so on, all the way up to the global scope. Every scope level adds a very slight overhead.

But again, don't do these optimizations unless you're sure they will make a noticeable difference. Readable, understandable code is important for it to work the way it should, now and in the future.

Here's a full profiling using Firebug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Benchmark scope lookup</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        function bench_window_Math_round() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                window.Math.round(1.23);
            }
        }

        function bench_Math_round() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                Math.round(1.23);
            }
        }

        function bench_round() {
            for (var i = 0, round = Math.round; i < 100000; i++) {
                round(1.23);
            }
        }

        console.log('Profiling will begin in 3 seconds...');
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.profile();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                bench_window_Math_round();
                bench_Math_round();
                bench_round();
            }
            console.profileEnd();
        }, 3000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My results:
`Time` shows total for 100,000 * 10 calls, `Avg`/`Min`/`Max` show time for 100,000 calls.

```
Calls  Percent  Own Time   Time       Avg        Min        Max
bench_window_Math_round
10     86.36%   1114.73ms  1114.73ms  111.473ms  110.827ms  114.018ms   
bench_Math_round
10      8.21%    106.04ms   106.04ms   10.604ms   10.252ms   13.446ms   
bench_round
10      5.43%     70.08ms    70.08ms    7.008ms    6.884ms    7.092ms
```

As you can see, `window.Math` is a really bad idea. I guess accessing the global `window` object adds additional overhead. However, the difference between accessing the `Math` object from the global scope, and just accessing a local variable with a reference to the `Math.round` function isn't very great... Keep in mind that this is 100,000 calls, and the difference is only 3.6ms. Even with one million calls you'd only see a 36ms difference.

Things to think about with the above profiling code:

- The functions are actually looked up from another scope, which adds overhead (barely noticable though, I tried importing the functions into the anonymous function).
- The actual `Math.round` function adds overhead (I'm guessing about 6ms in 100,000 calls).

Comment: +1 for giving my use of var round = Math.round some validity.

Comment: nice job, you did a great job with the benchmarks. I wish I could give you a +2

Comment: I have recently run a test, and caching `var sin = Math.sin` caused a performance drop. Perhaps it's no longer recognised as a function that's implemented in x86 natively?

Comment: @JanDvorak `sin` is heavier than `round` so it's likely that the very little overhead caused by the additional `Math` lookup is so negligible that you won't be able to measure the difference among randomness. The actual execution of the function won't change though, since there's only one implementation.

Comment: Oh and like I said in the answer, this is petty optimization: it won't help any program out there since you would have to do millions of calls to save a few milliseconds. If you want to actually optimize code using `Math.sin`, Google for "sine lookup table".

Answer (score 3):

This can be an interest question if you want to know how the [Scope Chain and the Identifier Resolution](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.4) process works.

The scope chain is a list of objects that are searched when evaluating an identifier, those objects are not accessible by code, only its properties (identifiers) can be accessed.

At first, in global code, the scope chain is created and initialised to contain only the global object.

The subsequent objects in the chain are created when you enter in function execution context and by the `with` statement and `catch` clause, both also introduce objects into the chain.

For example:

```
// global code
var var1 = 1, var2 = 2;
(function () { // one
  var var3 = 3;
  (function () { // two
    var var4 = 4;

    with ({var5: 5}) { // three
      alert(var1);
    }
  })();
})();
```

In the above code, the scope chain will contain different objects in different levels, for example, at the lowest level, within the `with` statement, if you use the `var1` or `var2` variables, the scope chain will contain 4 objects that will be needed to inspect in order to get that identifier: the one introduced by the `with` statement, the two functions, and finally the global object.

You also need to know that `window` is *just a property* that exists in the global object and it *points to the global object itself*. `window` is introduced by browsers, and in other environments often it isn't available.

In conclusion, when you use `window`, since it is just an identifier (is not a reserved word or anything like that) and it needs to pass all the resolution process in order to get the global object, `window.Math` needs an additional step that is made by the dot (`.`) property accessor.

Answer (score 2):

JS performance differs widely from browser to browser.

My advice: benchmark it. Just put it in a for loop, let it run a few million times, and time it.... see what you get. Be sure to share your results!

Answer (score 1):

(As you've said) `Math.floor` will probably just be a shortcut for `window.Math` (as `window` is a Javascript global object) in most Javascript implementations such as V8.

Spidermonkey and V8 will be so heavily optimised for common usage that it shouldn't be a concern.

For readability my preference would be to use `Math.floor`, the difference in speed will be so insignificant it's not worth worrying about ever. If you're doing a 100,000 floors it's probably time to switch that logic out of the client.

You may want to have a nose around the v8 source there's some interesting comments there about shaving nanoseconds off functions such as [this](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#W9JxUuHYyMg/trunk/src/v8natives.js&q=v8natives.js%20package:http://v8%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) `int.Parse()` one.

```
// Some people use parseInt instead of Math.floor.  This
// optimization makes parseInt on a Smi 12 times faster (60ns
// vs 800ns).  The following optimization makes parseInt on a
// non-Smi number 9 times faster (230ns vs 2070ns).  Together
// they make parseInt on a string 1.4% slower (274ns vs 270ns).
```

Comment: @Mark Yeh all the answers are really confirming what you already believe.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, although I should have phrased the question better so that it focused more on the performance part and less on the window. notation +1.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand JavaScript logic, everything you refer to as `something` is searched in the global variable scope. In browser implementations, the `window` object *is* the global object. Hence, when you are asking for `window.Math` you actually have to de-reference what `window` means, then get its properties and find `Math` there. If you simply ask for `Math`, the first place where it is sought, is the global object.

So, yes- calling `Math.something` will be faster than `window.Math.something`.

D. Crockeford talks about it in his lecture http://video.yahoo.com/watch/111593/1710507, as far as I recall, it's in the 3rd part of the video.

Answer (score 0):

If `Math.round()` is being called in a local/function scope the interpreter is going to have to check first for a local var then in the global/window space. So in local scope my guess would be that `window.Math.round()` would be very slightly faster. This isn't assembly, or C or C++, so I wouldn't worry about which is faster for *performance* reasons, but if out of curiosity, sure, benchmark it.

Comment: `window.Math.round()` would still need to look for a local `window` variable.