# Why is it beneficial to rely on the scope chain alone and avoid explicitly referencing the head object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope, global

I've been reading this book "Javascript Enlightenment" by Cody Lindley. On page 82 he states: "Being explicit (e.g. window.alert() v.s. alert()) costs a little bit more with regards to performance. It's faster if you rely on the scope chain alone and avoid explicitly referencing the head object even if you know the property you want is contained in the global scope."

I am kind of curious why this is. I would think that it would be the opposite, because the Javascript interpreter could just skip checking the scope and find it directly. I just don't see how it is beneficial to not specify the exact address of something.

I mean, I know I am not going to want to type window.whatever() every time I want to use something contained in the global scope and I think it is great that it is faster to not specify. Just not sure why.

Just one of those "want to know" things.

Comment: Good question.  I would think the same as you that `window.alert()` would be faster than just `alert()`.

Comment: `'window'` has to be looked up, and then `'alert'`. Two lookups will always be slower than one.

Comment: I think I am going to test it out to see how true it is. My guess is the difference will be so negligible that I won't be able to tell with console.time(). This book has been really good, so I bet he is right.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about micro-optimizations like these...

Comment: Not too worried. Just curious. I am going to use just plain old alert() even if window.alert() were faster. Because I am lazy!

Comment: Remember that premature optimization is the root of all evil. And yes, the difference is negligible (both of these operate at millions of ops/sec), I'd recommend writing the one you're used with. Here's the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/scope-chain-vs-window) for testing, already with my FF19 Nightly, Chrome 24 Canary and IE9 results.

Comment: related: [In javascript, is accessing 'window.Math' slower or faster than accessing the 'Math' object without the 'window.'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2125113/1048572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The interpreter always has to use the scope chain. When you write `window.alert()` it has to walk its way up the scope chain to find the value of `window` -- you might have a local variable named `window` that shadows the one in the head, so it can't assume this is the global object.

If JavaScript had a syntax to explicitly denote the top-level context, that would be faster. But it doesn't.