# Any real difference between window.prompt and prompt?

Tags: javascript, prompt

Just out of curiosity is there any difference between window.prompt and prompt in JavaScript.

For one of the answers to my exam questions the teacher uses

```
var yourName = window.prompt("Please enter your first name here\n");
```

and I used

```
var yourName = prompt("Please enter your first name here\n");
```

It is a written exam so i felt it wouldn't make much difference.

Comment: Nope, they're the same.

Comment: when you declare a variable that is in the root scope, you can find it inside `window.` as well. `var test = 10;` `window.test` will be 10. therefore they are exactly the same function (not a copy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually yes, `window.prompt === prompt`. Yet it does depend on your scope, someone might have declared `window` or `prompt` variables with different values than those in the global scope.

For further details have a look at [Is window really global in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6679635/1048572). You (and your teacher) also might be interested in [Why is it beneficial to rely on the scope chain alone and avoid explicitly referencing the head object in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13022647/1048572).

Comment: Thank you, will look at these links you sent as well.

Answer (score 0):

var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

if (person != null) {

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =

"Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
}

usually window.prompt === prompt because,

A prompt dialog contains a single-line textbox, a Cancel button, and an OK button, and returns the (possibly empty) text the user entered into that textbox. ... alert Dialog boxes are modal windows; they prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed

Comment: Please add some comments on your code illustration to answer the question more completely, especially for those less experienced .  Might even make a snippet of the code to show it working

Comment: Usually yes, window.prompt === prompt. Yet it does depend on your scope, someone might have declared window or prompt variables with different values than those in the global scope.

Comment: @Muhammadwasi Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184598/any-real-difference-between-window-prompt-and-prompt#comment120920239_68413919), apparently corresponding to a segment from the previously [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23184837/1) in the same thread, does not include the [necessary attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). Was it intentional for some reason, or did you miss it unknowingly? If yes, please scan — https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Comment: No differance brother  just developers used the short form for prompt both are work as a same.