# Prompt vs Window.prompt

Tags: javascript, dom

Is `prompt('Whatever')` the same as `window.prompt('Whatever')`?

Should I be using `window.prompt` or `window.alert` instead of just `prompt` or `alert`? Is there any performance or compatibility differences?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: similar like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184598/any-real-difference-between-window-prompt-and-prompt  please check tihs out

Comment: Ok sorry I didnt see that one :) Ill close this one :D

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `window` is the global object. You can call `prompt` either by referencing the global object `window.prompt('Whatever')` or  by it's shorthand `prompt('Whatever')`.

Both are **same**.